# What type should I use to store values like "999999.99" in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-node-driver

I wanna add a price column to my table to be able to store values from `0.0` to `999999.99`. I tried `price DECIMAL(8,2)` but it seems it doesn't work. How can I store such a value?

I am also wondering to know if there would be any pre-post processing needed after that because I use NodeJS/TypeScript in  backend that handles all numeric values using `number` type!

I also like to know if is it a better idea to use string type insted?

EDIT: For example if I try

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.test(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  price DECIMAL(8,2));
```

I get:

> SyntaxException: line 3:15 no viable alternative at input '(' (...
> TEXT PRIMARY KEY,  price DECIMAL

But the following works with no problems:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.test(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  price INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage `decimal` type or even use `float` data types in Cassandra. See https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html for more details. And, with NodeJS Driver, https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/features/datatypes/ the CQL `decimal` data type maps to `BigDecimal` JS type. `float` CQL data type maps to `Number` JS type and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect which is the reason for the `SyntaxException`.

It is not possible to specify the precision in CQL since the `decimal` type is a variable-precision Java type.

Simply declare the column as `decimal` type, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE decimals (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    price decimal
)
```

and deal with the precision in your code instead. Cheers!